# Taxonomy exposed filter in views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, views

I have a content type with a field 'field_departimage' which uses entity reference to reference a taxonomy I have set up which holds the name and image.

I would like to filter by the taxonomy 'name' in views but I'm having some issues linking them

I am able to display the taxonomy but they don't seem to be linking to node to filter correctly. I'm probably doing something wrong with the contextual filters or in the relationships section.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: sorry updated my question

Answer (score 0):

In views you need to add in relationship "Taxonomy term: field name" and in contextual filters you need to set "(field_name) Taxonomy term: Name" or "(field_name) Taxonomy term: Id".

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the content type
2. Select the field (in my case 'field_departimage') and edit settings.
3. At the bottom, select Render Views filters as select list

[image: Render Views filters]